# Find all the positions where a substring matches a stirng

Tags: python

I want to get the indexes for all the ocurrencies of substring inside a string

```
s = "the bewildered tourist was in the mosque"
w = "the"

find(s,t)
[1, 31]
```

I also want the function to start counting on 1, as in the previous example, instead of 0.

This is what I managed:

```
import re

def find(sentence, word):
    if word in sentence:
        matches = re.finditer(word, sentence)
        matches_positions = [match.start() for match in matches]
        print(matches_positions)
    
    else:
        return [-1]
        
find(s, w)
[0, 30]
```

This is working, but I would like a way of doing this without using any `import`, as well as starting at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: What is your question about this? What was the problem when you wrote the code to do this without using the `re` module?

Comment: `… but I would like a way of doing this without using any import`. Why? The regex module is *part or Python*. Choosing not to use it (if it's the best tool) just because it doesn't load by default is a poor way of making that choice.

Comment: To make it start at 1, just add 1 to the indexes you find. `[match.start() + 1 for match in matches]`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the regular expression functionality to search for substrings if you don't need any regular expression matching.

To solve with just the standard methods available:

```
def find_indexes(string_to_search, word_to_find):
    start_index = 0
    positions = []

    while True:
        try:
            start_index = string_to_search.index(word_to_find, start_index)
            positions.append(start_index)
            start_index += len(word_to_find)
        except ValueError:
            return positions
 
    return positions
 
s = "the bewildered tourist was in the mosque"
w = "the"

print(find_indexes(s, w))
```

`index` raises an `ValueError` exception if the word can't be found after the given index, so we catch that and return the current indexes when it gets generated. `index` takes the start index as its second argument.

To make it start at `1` instead, add `1` to the index when you store it:

```
positions.append(start_index + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it the string into a list and find the index of each item where the value of `w` is found. This will give you the position of the word (not the position of the string).

```
s = "the bewildered tourist was in the mosque"
w = "the"
ss = s.split(' ')
print ([i for i,si in enumerate(ss) if si == w])
```

The output of this will be:

```
[0, 5]
```

Similarly, if you want to find the position of the string, can search for the word `the` (or var `w`), then print the position. To use the similar approach as above, you can do:

```
print ([i+1 for i in range(len(s)-len(w)-1) if s[i:i+len(2)] == w])
```

This will return:

```
[1, 31]
```

The `i+1` is to give you the starting position of 1 instead of 0.

The first result will return the position of the words and the second will return the position within the string.

Comment: Why are you splitting into words? The question is about finding the indexes of substrings, not words.

Comment: Got it. Updated the response to provide both words and substring.

Comment: It would be better if you used `len(w)` instead of hard-coding `-2` and `+3`

Comment: Agree with you. Updating it to len(w). It would work for any len of w.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is about 10x slower that using `index()` in a loop like @MatsLindh, which is measurably slower than just using `re.finditer` which the OP started with.